# Decode chr() function?

Tags: php

Hey guys been hitting hard on google and stackoverflow on this one...

I got php files encoded with php chr() function here is some of the code:

```
   <?php require_once chr(65).chr(100).chr(109).chr(105).chr(110).chr(67).chr(111).chr(110).chr(116).chr(114).chr(111).chr(108).chr(108).chr(101).chr(114).chr(46).chr(112).chr(104).chr(112);class WP_Amazonimportproducts_ImportController extends WP_Amazonimportproducts_AdminController{protected function _isAllowed(){return Mage::getSingleton(chr(97).chr(100).chr(109).chr(105).chr(110).chr(47).chr(115).chr(101).chr(115).chr(115).chr(105).chr(111).chr(110))->{"isAllowed"}(chr(99).chr(97).chr(116).chr(97).chr(108).chr(111).chr(103).chr(47).chr(97).chr(109).chr(97).chr(122).chr(111).chr(110).chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116).chr(112).chr(114).chr(111).chr(100).chr(117).chr(99).chr(116).chr(115).chr(47).chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116));}protected function _initImport(){$this->{"_title"}($this->{"__"}(chr(67).chr(97).chr(116).chr(97).chr(108).chr(111).chr(103)))->{"_title"}($this->{"__"}(chr(87).chr(80).chr(58).chr(32).chr(65).chr(109).chr(97).chr(122).chr(111).chr(110).chr(32).chr(73).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116)))->{"_title"}($this->{"__"}(chr(73).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116).chr(32).chr(80).chr(114).chr(111).chr(100).chr(117).chr(99).chr(116).chr(115)));return $this;}protected function _initProduct(){$   =Mage::getModel(chr(99).chr(97).chr(116).chr(97).chr(108).chr(111).chr(103).chr(47).chr(112).chr(114).chr(111).chr(100).chr(117).chr(99).chr(116));$    =Mage::getSingleton(chr(97).chr(100).chr(109).chr(105).chr(110).chr(47).chr(115).chr(101).chr(115).chr(115).chr(105).chr(111).chr(110))->{"getImportSettings"}();if (isset ($    [chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116).chr(95).chr(112).chr(97).chr(114).chr(97).chr(109).chr(115)][chr(99).chr(97).chr(116).chr(101).chr(103).chr(111).chr(114).chr(121).chr(95).chr(105).chr(100).chr(115)])){$   ->{"setCategoryIds"}($    [chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116).chr(95).chr(112).chr(97).chr(114).chr(97).chr(109).chr(115)][chr(99).chr(97).chr(116).chr(101).chr(103).chr(111).chr(114).chr(121).chr(95).chr(105).chr(100).chr(115)]);
```

I have been trying to find a decoder as far I understand you can use ord() php function to decode it? I have found a script to encode text to chr(65) if it was possible to reverse it to make it decode php scripts encoded with chr(111).chr(65) it would be amazing I got few pages I need to decode and the only way I can think it will work if it can skip non chr(65) code so I can paste the whole page and decode it. What do you guys think? How can I decode it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Convert String To PHP ASCII in PHP chr() function</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Convert String To PHP ASCII in PHP chr() function:</b><br /><br />
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
            <textarea name="s" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <br />  

        <?php
        $string = stripslashes($_GET['s']); 
        $chrstring = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $chrstring .= "chr(" . ord(substr($string,$i,1)) . ")";
            $chrstring .= ($i==strlen($string)-1)?"":".";       
        }   

        $toscreenstring = htmlentities($string);

        echo "<b>Converted:</b><br />$toscreenstring<br /><b>To:</b><br />$chrstring<br /><br />-"; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit!** I have found a php script with similar function to decode this thing but it works on number only (with out chr(number).chr(number) and need to make it skip non chr(number) so it will be possible to paste the whole script and it will decode what needed.

```
   <?php

   $charset = array(
        32 => ' ', 33 => '!', 34 => '"', 35 => '#', 36 => '$',
        37 => '%', 38 => '&', 39 => "'", 40 => '(', 41 => ')',
        42 => '*', 43 => '+', 44 => ',', 45 => '-', 46 => '.',
        47 => '/', 48 => '0', 49 => '1', 50 => '2', 51 => '3',
        52 => '4', 53 => '5', 54 => '6', 55 => '7', 56 => '8',
        57 => '9', 58 => ':', 59 => ';', 60 => '<', 61 => '=',
        62 => '>', 63 => '?', 64 => '@', 65 => 'A', 66 => 'B',
        67 => 'C', 68 => 'D', 69 => 'E', 70 => 'F', 71 => 'G',
        72 => 'H', 73 => 'I', 74 => 'J', 75 => 'K', 76 => 'L',
        77 => 'M', 78 => 'N', 79 => 'O', 80 => 'P', 81 => 'Q',
        82 => 'R', 83 => 'S', 84 => 'T', 85 => 'U', 86 => 'V',
        87 => 'W', 88 => 'X', 89 => 'Y', 90 => 'Z', 91 => '[',
        92 => '\\', 93 => ']', 94 => '^', 95 => '_', 96 => '`',
        97 => 'a', 98 => 'b', 99 => 'c', 100 => 'd', 101 => 'e',
        102 => 'f', 103 => 'g', 104 => 'h', 105 => 'i', 106 => 'j',
        107 => 'k', 108 => 'l', 109 => 'm', 110 => 'n', 111 => 'o',
        112 => 'p', 113 => 'q', 114 => 'r', 115 => 's', 116 => 't',
        117 => 'u', 118 => 'v', 119 => 'w', 120 => 'x', 121 => 'y',
        122 => 'z', 123 => '{', 124 => '|', 125 => '}'
    );

     function fromNumber($number)
    {
        $string = '';
        while($number)
        {
            $value = substr($number, 0, 2);
            $number = substr($number, 2);

            if($value < 32)
            {
                $value .= substr($number, 0, 1);
                $number = substr($number, 1);
            }

            $string .= $charset[ (int) $value];
        }
        return $string;
    }

 function fromString($string)
    {
        $number = '';
        foreach(str_split($string) as $char) $number .= ord($char);
        return $number;
    }


$string = 'this is my test string to convert';

$number = fromString($string);
$string = fromNumber($number);


?>
```

Comment: Just replace `require_once` with `echo`.

Comment: @Gumbo and where should I execute this PHP? I tried with TryItEditor it says Error

Comment: @Gumbo ran it at the server and it echoed only the first function but there is a lot more the rest where errors like Fatal error: Class 'WP_Amazonimportproducts_AdminController' not found in

Comment: @MarkVoidale [Here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fns-3iy) for example

Comment: @Voitcus http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ek5-421 here you go the full code there is no way to decode it with echo I mean you can but it will take ages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function callback($hits){
    return chr($hits['1']);
}
$php_content = file_get_contents("./myFile.php");
$php_content = preg_replace_callback('/chr\((\d+)\)(\.|)/', "callback", $php_content));
file_put_contents("./myFile.php", $php_content);
```

Just loop it until all your files are 'decoded'

**EDIT:**

You just need to know all files wich are unreadable and put them into this array like:

```
$files = array();
$files[] = "./folder/file1.php";
$files[] = "./folder/file2.php";
$files[] = "./folder/file3.php";
$files[] = "./folder2/file4.php";
$files[] = "./folder2/file5.php";
$files[] = "./file1.php";

foreach($files as $file){
    $php_content = file_get_contents(file);
    $php_content = preg_replace_callback('/chr\((\d+)\)(\.|)/', "callback", $php_content));
    file_put_contents(file, $php_content);
}
```

Or if it is an entire folder of files and all subfolders and so on have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: Hey it does seems like it! Can you clarify how to loop it? I put it inside loop.php and the page to decode in the same folder named it as myFile.php ran the script in the url nothing happened :)

Comment: Updated my answer. This script will read teh php-file, replace the chr(x) with the char and put it back into the php-file so teh script itselt ( loop.php ) will show nothing but you file will be readable ( if no errors are shown )

Answer (score 0):

The encoded line is `require_once 'AdminController.php' ;`  [here is the echoed value](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7XShFT)
when You replaced `require_once` to `echo` the inclusion was canceled, because of that you received the error 'Fatal error: Class 'WP_Amazonimportproducts_AdminController' not found'. In your code you can echo and require the statement.

```
...    
require_once chr(65).chr(100).chr(109).chr(105).chr(110).chr(67).chr(111).chr(110).chr(116).chr(114).chr(111).chr(108).chr(108).chr(101).chr(114).chr(46).chr(112).chr(104).chr(112);        
echo chr(65).chr(100).chr(109).chr(105).chr(110).chr(67).chr(111).chr(110).chr(116).chr(114).chr(111).chr(108).chr(108).chr(101).chr(114).chr(46).chr(112).chr(104).chr(112);
...
```

Comment: This is just 1 small part of the bigger php you cannot echo the whole php file check this http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ek5-421 I got 5 pages like this it will take to set echo to more than 100 functions echo is not a solution in this case

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it is not the answer you expect, but while you know how to decode it, and because it is too difficult to write a php program just to parse another php file, I would do this way, that I would load the file to something like MS Word or any other text processor, it can be a notepad, search (Ctrl-F) for a `require`/`include` and delete every line that doesn't contain it and then just `echo` what is left, as Vahe Shadunts wrote.

I know this is not an answer for your question ("how to do it in php?"), but I really think it is not worth effort, as you probably have not so many include or require functions. Writing a PHP program is not optimal in this case, in my opinion.

Comment: I think a function that I need is very simple just like the code i have edited recently it does almost what I need small changes to that code and it will bulk change the whole php file into a readable so I do think it's worth it. It should be easy because it's simple. I need a function to read whole php file and every chr(100) change with ord() function to letter in the end i will get what I need...